# Why I can't read the change of global variables in a nested function?

Tags: javascript, nested-function

//this is a code question about nested functions and timer function

```js
    var num = 0; //the key of this problem
 var timer = null;
 timer = setInterval(function() {
        //num could change from 0 to 9 in this function
  console.log(num); 
  setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(num); //but in this place, num is always 0,why?
  }, 2000); 

  num++;     
  if (num >= 10) {      
   num = 0;
  clearInterval(timer);
  }
 }, 100);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why I can't read the change of global variables in a nested function?

You are. It's just a logic error, by the time your `setTimeout` callbacks occur, you've set it *back* to 0: You increment `num` every 100ms, setting it to 0 when it reaches 10 and then stopping the increment process. After 2000ms, you show the value of `num`. At that point, it's going to be 0, because it reached 0 after 10 loops at 100ms intervals, a second earlier.

Put another way, here's what happens:

1. Time 0ms: You set `num` to 0
2. Time 0ms: You set up a repeating interval timer (`setInterval`) at 100ms
3. Time ~100ms: The interval fires the first time:

   1. It sets up the first callback for 2000ms later
   2. Changes `num` to 1
4. Time ~200ms: The interval fires the second time:

   1. It sets up the first callback for 2000ms later
   2. Changes `num` to 2
5. That happens again at ~300ms (num -> 3), ~400ms (num -> 4), ~500ms (num -> 5), ~600ms (num -> 6), ~700ms (num -> 7), ~800ms (num -> 8), ~900ms (num -> 3)
6. Time ~1000ms: The interval fires the last time:

   1. It sets up yet another callback for 2000ms later
   2. It sets num to 10, then to 0 and cancels the interval
7. Time ~2100ms: The first `setTimeout` callback fires, showing num = 0
8. Time ~2200ms: The second `setTimeout` callback fires, showing num = 0
9. ...and so on